# Mongoose find with multiple matches

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm new to this technology and working with Node and Express server that uses Mongoose. I have following schema for a document collection.

```js
var empSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
 _id: String,
 orgName: {type: String, required: true},
 locName: {type: String, required: true},
 empName: {type: String, required: true}
});
```

Here I get a list of location names like "NewYork", "London", "Paris" etc... in a request and needs to return the documents in the response as following....

```js
{
result:[{locName:"NewYork",
 empList:[
  {orgName:"abc", empName:"emp1"},
  {orgName:"xyz", empName:"emp2"}]
 },
 {locName:"London",
 empList:[
  {orgName:"pkq", empName:"emp13"},
  {orgName:"mns", empName:"emp23"}]
 }]
}
```

What would be the best way to use mongoose from Node. I think making multiple queries (each one with a location) to mongodb is a bad idea.

Is there a way to get the expected json response with single call to mongoose? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, use the **[aggregation framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-introduction/)** to get the desired output. The aggregation pipeline will consist of a [**`$group`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group) operator pipeline stage which groups the documents by the `locName` field and the [**`$addToSet`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addToSet/#grp._S_addToSet) accumulator operator to add the `orgName` and `empName` fields to an array `empList`. The last pipeline stage [**`$project`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project) operator then replaces the `_id` field from the previous aggregation stream with a new field `locName`.

To demonstrate this concept, suppose you have a sample collection which you insert with mongo shell:

```
db.employees.insert([
    {
        _id: "1",
        orgName: "abc",
        locName: "New York",
        empName: "emp1"
    },
    {
        _id: "2",
        orgName: "xyz",
        locName: "New York",
        empName: "emp2"
    },
    {
        _id: "3",
        orgName: "pkq",
        locName: "London",
        empName: "emp13"
    },
    {
        _id: "4",
        orgName: "mns",
        locName: "London",
        empName: "emp23"
    }
])
```

The following aggregation produces the desired result:

```
db.employees.aggregate([
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$locName",
            "empList": {
                "$addToSet": {
                    "orgName": "$orgName",
                    "empName": "$empName"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "$project": {
            "_id": 0,
            "locName": "$_id",
            "empList": 1
        }
    }
])
```

**Output**:

```
/* 0 */
{
    "result" : [ 
        {
            "empList" : [ 
                {
                    "orgName" : "mns",
                    "empName" : "emp23"
                }, 
                {
                    "orgName" : "pkq",
                    "empName" : "emp13"
                }
            ],
            "locName" : "London"
        }, 
        {
            "empList" : [ 
                {
                    "orgName" : "xyz",
                    "empName" : "emp2"
                }, 
                {
                    "orgName" : "abc",
                    "empName" : "emp1"
                }
            ],
            "locName" : "New York"
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

In Mongoose, you can use the **[aggregation pipeline](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.aggregate)** builder like this:

```
Employee.aggregate()
        .group({
            "_id": "$locName",
            "empList": {
                "$addToSet": {
                    "orgName": "$orgName",
                    "empName": "$empName"
                }
            }
        })
        .project({
            "_id": 0,
            "locName": "$_id",
            "empList": 1
        })
        .exec(function (err, res) {
            if (err) return handleError(err);
            console.log(res); 
    });

// Or the simple aggregate method
var pipeline = [
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$locName",
            "empList": {
                "$addToSet": {
                    "orgName": "$orgName",
                    "empName": "$empName"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "$project": {
            "_id": 0,
            "locName": "$_id",
            "empList": 1
        }
    }
]

Employee.aggregate(pipeline, function (err, res) {
    if (err) return handleError(err);
    console.log(res); 
});
```

Comment: Very nice and clear detailed one. You made my day, Thanks a lot.

Comment: @harik No worries :-)

Answer (score 1):

All queries, when you need to group by sum values called aggregate. You can read about it in the [mongo docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) and same methods have model in [Mongoose](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.aggregate). To produce your query, you can use code like this:

```
Employee
  .aggregate()
  .group({ _id: '$locName', empList: { $push: "$$ROOT" }})
  .exec(function (err, res) {

});
```

If you need not to query all table, there is also have a [match](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#aggregate_Aggregate-match) method.